# Return a list of objects of class that implements an interface

Tags: c#, reflection

Say I have a class structure like this:

```
public class Student
{

}

public class Undergraduate : Student
{

}

public class Postgraduate : Student
{

}
```

Is it possible to return an instance of all the classes that inherit from Student in a list like this:

```
List<Student> Student = new List<Student>
```

I am wandering if this can be done using reflection:

```
Student.Add(new PostGraduate);
Student.Add(new UnderGraduate);
```

I believe I have to use reflection for this.  I have tried this:

```
var type = typeof(Student);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

However, this does not return a type of Undergraduate and a type of graduate in a list.

Comment: What does your code return now? Which types are in `types`? What is `types.Count()`?

Comment: Are you sure that all your assemblies are loaded into the AppDomain?  Assemblies are loaded into the AppDomain until they are hit in code.

Comment: @Servy Is that duplicate really relevant? The OP is currently having issues **getting** the list of types to create. He / she may run into the duplicate issue later - but it isn't their _current_ issue.